# Каким способом можно переключать окна как в Kate mobile?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Если кто-то видел навбар в кейт мобайл - три вкладки профиль - новости - сообщения, на моем сайте три блока (на большом екране), с разной тематикой, использую бутстрап и по умолчанию на маленьком екране смартфона все блоки размещаються один под другим, но мне этого не надо, будет неудобно, и тут пришла идея сделать навбар как в приложении кейт. иcкал много информации но так и не нашел, как можно реализовать такое в браузере? чтоб при уменьшении екрана все становилось примерно таким
[image: Kate mobile]

Comment: Вы в курсе про media запросы или вам нужен какой нибудь инструмент что бы самому все не писать? https://webref.ru/css/value/media

Comment: @Bleser, нет, но сецчас почитаю) спасибо) я буду сам писать

Comment: Подобные вкладки называются "табы" ищите в этом направлении. В бутстрапе вроде есть.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров я знаю, читал о них, но проблема в том что их мне не надо в обычном режиме, только на смартфонах, как сделать так чтоб автоматически переключалось?